# Object defined error on data validation. Data validation in VBA error

Tags: excel, vba

I'm getting an application or object-defined error on the bolded line. What is going on? Everything else seems to check out. Code searches for a cell containing 2021, then retrieves the cell address and pushes the column letter to the variable indicated. Thats good.

```
Private Sub Validation2()
  
  Dim CLM As String
  Dim ws As Worksheet
  Dim cellvalue2 As Range
  Dim rng As Range
  Dim columnletterm As String
  Dim rvGHOCPD As Range
  Dim rGHOCPD As Range
  Dim rGHOCPD2 As Range
  Dim rv As Range

  Set rng = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Monthly").Range("A1:DD1")
        

  For Each cellvalue2 In rng
  
      If cellvalue2.Value Like "*2021" Then
  
            With ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Monthly")
            
            CLM = cellvalue2.Address
            
            columnletterm = Split(CLM, "$")(1)
            
            End With                

        Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Monthly")
        Set rvGHOCPD = ws.Range(columnletterm & "66", columnletterm & "81")
        Set rGHOCPD = ws.Range(columnletterm & "6").Offset(0, 1)
        Set rGHOCPD2 = ws.Range(columnletterm & "6").Offset(0, 2)            
        
        Set rv = ws.Range(rGHOCPD, rGHOCPD2)

        With rv.Validation
            .Delete
            **.Add Type:=xlValidateList, Formula1:="='" & ws.name & "'!" & rvGHOCPD.Address**
            .IgnoreBlank = True
            .InCellDropdown = True
            .InputTitle = ""
            .ErrorTitle = ""
            .InputMessage = ""
            .ErrorMessage = ""
            .ShowInput = True
            .ShowError = True
        End With
    End if
Next cellvalue2
end Sub
```

Comment: Instead of xlValidateList, try xlValidateCustom

Comment: receiving same error

Comment: Please, try `.Add Type:=xlValidateList, Formula1:="='" & ws.name & "'!" & rvGHOCPD.Address(0, 0)`. I think the formula must have relative references...

Comment: it's recognizing the address and sheetname, but still getting the error.